# How to handle "Invalid JSON RPC response" using infura.io and web3

Tags: web3js, infura

I'm new in the world of Ethereum and I'm building a app with node.js.

I'm using web3 1.0 and infura to connect to a contract and get all the logs for different events. I'm using the "getPastEvents" function from web3.

I'm getting this error time to time "**Invalid JSON RPC response**".

Right now, when I get this error, I just restart the app and if it passes good if not well i restart again... I'm putting a setTimout function so my app restart by itself. But because of that error, my app is crashing and doing an exit.

How can I handle this error ? any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you post any code that you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some [problems with web3 1.0 and events via Infura](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/989).

And since web3.js 1.0 is not yet released, the best advise is to use web3 version 0.2x.x.

Take a look [at this](https://github.com/bordalix/ethereum-roulette/blob/master/src/js/app.js#L74) on how to initiate an event listener on web3 0.2x.x

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good to know... do you have any examples to be able to get past events in web3 version 0.2x.x. ?

Comment: Edited the answer with a link to a repo of mine, where I initiate the event listener in a web3 0.2x.x dapp. If you find this answer satisfactory, please mark it as such, it helps other people to find answers to their questions. Thank you.

Comment: your code would be the same if i wanted to do it in node.js ?

Comment: it should work also with node.js.

Comment: The event will fire inside the `(err, res) => {...}` so don't close it, and put your code inside the block ({}).